# BASH regular expression to match days of week

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to find a better way to match the days of the week in my bash script. Here's what I have that works:

```
if [[ $LINE == *"Sun"* ]] || [[ $LINE == *"Mon"* ]] || [[ $LINE == *"Tue"* ]] || [[ $LINE == *"Wed"* ]] || [[ $LINE == *"Thu"* ]] || [[ $LINE == *"Fri"* ]] || [[ $LINE == *"Sat"* ]]; then
```

All lines in the file I am parsing start with Mon through Sun:

```
Mon  cat  dog  bird
Tue  bird cat  dog
```

But I know there must be a better way. I've tried many things, here are a couple of failures:

```
DAYS_REGEX='*[S|M|T|W|F][u|o|e|h|r|a][n|e|d|u|i|t]*'
if [[ $LINE =~ $DAYS_REGEX ]] ; then
```

and

```
if [[ $LINE == *"Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat"* ]] ; then
```

I feel like there should be a regex that would be something like this but I can't pin it down:

(SMTWF/uoehra/neduit)

What I have works but I'm trying to learn how to incorporate regex into my bash scripts. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. TIA

Comment: Stupid question: if your lines all *start* with the day of the week, then why do your existing glob-patterns have `*` at the beginning?

Comment: I found that piece of code on the web and expanded it to include all the days of the week. Now that I'm starting to work with regex I was wondering if I could remove those but I hadn't tried yet.

Comment: There ain't no *Regex* for days of week, you either name them all, or have a regex that matches kinda superset of them, where it's your risk that it might match something not exactly a day-of-week

Comment: @user2615269 `Sun|Mon|...|Sat` *is* a regular expression; it just also happens to be the shortest one that matches exactly one of the 7 (quite different) abbreviations for the days of the week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match a regex:

```
if [[ $LINE =~ Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat ]]; then
  echo match
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a case statement:

```
case "$LINE" in
    Mon*|Tue*|Wed*|Thu*|Fri*|Sat*|Sun*)
        echo "Some logic here..."
        ;;
esac
```

Then you can split this out into separate logic for individual days if you need to:

```
case "$LINE" in
    Mon*|Tue*|Wed*)
        echo "Different logic"
        ;;
    Thu*|Fri*|Sat*|Sun*)
        echo "Some logic here..."
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: It's better to be explicit like the above, rather than something that's nearly unreadable like the following `DAYS_REGEX='*[S|M|T|W|F][u|o|e|h|r|a][n|e|d|u|i|t]*'`

Comment: Ah! I've never used or seen case before. This is interesting and I'll check it out. Thank you!